# Refreshing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I'm using the following code to retrieve a simple list of tweets containing a certain hash tag:

```
$(document).ready(function tweetList() {
$.getJSON(
    'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=20&q=web',
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, tweets) {
            for (var num = 0, len = tweets.length; num < len; num++) {
                if (tweets[num].text !== undefined) {
                    var tim = new Date(tweets[num].created_at);
                    var author = tweets[num].from_user;
                    $('ul#tweets').append('<li><b>' + tim.toString().substring(0, 24) + ':</b> ' + tweets[num].text + author + '</li>');   
                }
            }
        });
        setInterval(tweetList, 5000);
    }
);
});</script>

<ul id="tweets"></ul>
```

As you can see I am trying to refresh the list, however the problem is that by refreshing the function, the list keeps growing with the refreshed data.

I know this is because I am using .append, however when I use .html the whole list of tweets doesn't get populated.

Is it possible to get around this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete your previous data before inserting new.

Before `$.each` write:

```
$('ul#tweets').html('');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to remove old tweets, but not all of them.  The:

```
$('ul#tweets').html('')
```

Will remove all old tweets before you update, but this will let you keep an arbitrary number of tweets (set by numToKeep);

```
var numToKeep=10;
var currSize = $('ul#tweets li').size();
var extras = numToKeep - currSize;
$('ul#tweets li').each(function(count,el){
   if (count < numToKeep) {
      $(el).remove();
   }
});
```

Since count is 0 based, this should remove old tweets.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$('#tweets').empty();
$.each(data, function(i, tweets) {
```